# Should event listeners be inside document.ready function or does it not matter?

Tags: jquery

When I use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

});
```

Should my event listeners (e.g `$('button').click(function(){})` go inside that doc.ready function or outside according to convention?

Comment: It all depends on where your logic runs, in the header or before the closing of your body.  This determines if you need a doc ready at all, or can optionally just use an IIFE if you want to provide scope.

Answer (score 7):

You should put anything in it that needs initialized AFTER the document object model is loaded. Including event listeners.

"Should my event listeners (e.g $('button').click(function(){}) go inside that doc.ready function or outside according to convention?"

HTML is interpreted from top to bottom so if your JS file is located in your head and you do not place it inside the .ready event then it will not be able to find your buttons since they haven't been generated yet.

If you put it inside your .ready event though, it is basically telling js to wait until the full dom object has been generated so the btn would then be found and bound.

On the other hand, there are people who strongly believe in including their js files at the very bottom of the page. Since HTML is interpreted from top to bottom then the js file will be loaded after the "meat" of the dom has been generated and you would not need to encapsulate your event binding inside .ready

Answer (score 0):

You should include all jQuery code inside of it.  Generally speaking, this is what I've seen most programmers do.  Additionally,  you should include your event listeners inside this section of code.  That way, if you were to load you jQuery code before your HTML, your code will still operate properly.