# After JQuery validation button click event not working ASP.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

```
    <div class="field">
        <label for="txtusername">Username</label>
        <div class="ui left labeled input">
            <asp:TextBox id="txtusername"

                type="text"
                data-validation="[L>=6, L<=18, MIXED]"
                data-validation-message="$ must be between 6 and 18 characters. No special characters allowed."
                runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>

            <div class="ui corner label">
                <i class="asterisk icon">*</i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="signup_v1-password">Password</label>
        <div class="ui left labeled input">

            <input id="signup_v1-password"
                name="signup_v1[password]"
                type="password" data-validation="[L>=6]"
                data-validation-message="$ must be at least 6 characters" />

            <div class="ui corner label">
                <i class="asterisk icon">*</i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <label for="signup_v1-email">Email</label>
        <div class="ui left labeled input">

            <input id="signup_v1-email"
                name="signup_v1[email]"
                type="text"
                data-validation="[EMAIL]" />

            <div class="ui corner label">
                <i class="asterisk icon">*</i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Sign up!" class="ui blue submit button" OnClick="Button1_Click1" />
    <%--<input type="submit" class="ui blue submit button" value="Sign up!">--%>

    <button id="prefill-signup_v1" type="button" class="ui mini basic button">
        Prefill
    </button>

    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>

</div>
```

```
<script>

    $('#form-signup_v1').validate({
        submit: {
            settings: {
                inputContainer: '.field'
            },
            callback: {
                onBeforeSubmit: function (node) {

                    myBeforeSubmitFunction(':D', ':)', node);

                },
                onSubmit: function (node) {

                    console.log('#' + node.id + ' has a submit override.');

                    //node.submit();

                }
            }
        },
        debug: true
    });

    function myBeforeSubmitFunction(a, b, node) {

        console.log(a, b);

        $(node).find('input:not([type="submit"]), select, textarea').attr('readonly', 'true');
        $(node).append('<div class="ui active loader"></div>');

    }

    $('#prefill-signup_v1').on('click', function () {

        var form = $(this).closest('form');

        form.find('#txtusername').val('');
        form.find('#signup_v1-username').val('');
        form.find('#signup_v1-password').val('');
        form.find('#signup_v1-password-confirm').val('');
        form.find('#signup_v1-email').val('');
        form.find('#signup_v1-email-confirm').val('');

    });

</script>
```

Comment: Where is your script tag being inserted into the page? This might be occurring if the browser parses the JavaScript before the buttons have been added to the DOM. See more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44445952/should-event-listeners-be-inside-document-ready-function-or-does-it-not-matter).

Comment: Can you help me?